# Riesz's lemma "upside down"

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have the following problem which I can solve if there is some sort of converse to Riesz (which I wasn't able to prove):

> If $X$ is an infinite dimentional normed vector space, prove there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n\not \in \overline{\text{span}\{x_j| j>n\}}$ for every $n$.

I tried using Zorn like this: take a certain $0\not= x_1\in X$ with unitary norm and consider the set $\mathcal{S}$ of all closed subspaces such that $d(x_1,S)\geq \frac{1}{2}$.  This set is partially ordered by inclusion. If we have a chain in $\{C_i| i \in I\}\subseteq \mathcal{S}$ we consider the following closed subspace:
$$C=\overline{\cup_{i\in I} C_i}$$

Clearly, if $c \in C$, we have that $\lVert c-c_i\rVert\leq \varepsilon$ for some $c_i\in C_i$.  Thus:

$$\lVert c-x\rVert\geq \lVert x-c_i \rVert-\lVert c_i-c\rVert\geq \frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon$$

Because $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, $d(x,C)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ and we have an upper bound to our chain. Hence, there is a maximal element in $\mathcal{S}$. Let us call this maximal element $X_1$. We repeat the process in $X_1$ to build a sequence such that $x_i\not \in X_i$ and all $\{x_j| j>i\}\subset X_i$ which is a closed subspace, which implies $\overline{\text{span}\{x_j| j>i\}}\subset X_i$.

**There is a flaw in this argument which can be overcome using something similar to Riesz but not quite Riesz:**

> We need (given a point $x$ in a normed vector space of norm $1$) to find closed subspaces far from it, namely $d(x,C)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ and we need these vector spaces to be large in dimension and plentiful enough such that $\mathcal{S}$ has a maximal element of infinite dimension.

Can my argument be salvaged, or is there a more natural approach?

Comment: @daw, it is not a Hilbert space so there is no inner product. But I think I know what to do: take a continuous function in $X^*$ not zero in $x_1$ and consider its Kernel (which is infinite dimensional by $\dim X=\dim Ker +\dim Im $) take the next element $x_2$ in the Kernel and repeat!  The Kernel is obviously closed because of continuity! But I am still curious about Riesz.

Comment: Why would $C = \overline{\cup_{i \in I}C_i}$ be a subspace? If the $C_i$ are lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ like $y=\lambda x$, for $-1 < \lambda < 1$ then it's not... (and they are exactly the subspaces with distance greater than 1/2 to the point $(0,\sqrt{2}/2)$).

Comment: @Ivr, please correct me, but I think it must be  a subspace because $C_i$  are contained in each other… It is a chain… Zorn’s lemma states we need only find a upper bounds in a chain…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a subspace $V\subseteq X$ denote $V'=V\setminus\{0\}$.

Let $\mathscr{F}=\{V':V\text{ is a subspace of }X\text{ of finite co-dimension}\}$.

By the axiom of choice, there is a function $\operatorname{ch}:\mathscr{F}\to X$  such that $\operatorname{ch}(V')\in V'$ for all $V'\in\mathscr{F}$.  By replacing $\operatorname{ch}(V')$ with $\operatorname{ch}(V')/\|\operatorname{ch}(V')\|$ we may assume $\|\operatorname{ch}(V')\|=1$.

Let $x_0=\operatorname{ch}(X')$.  By Hahn-Banach there is a bounded linear functional $\beta_0$ such that $\beta_0(x_0)=1$.  Let $K_0=\ker\beta_0$.

Let $x_1=\operatorname{ch}(K_0')$.  By Hanh-Banach there is a bounded linear functional $\beta_1$ such that $\beta_1(x_1)=1$.  Let $K_1=K_0\cap\ker\beta_1$.

Let $x_2=\operatorname{ch}(K_1')$.  By Hanh-Banach there is a bounded linear functional $\beta_2$ such that $\beta_2(x_2)=1$.  Let $K_2=K_1\cap\ker\beta_2$.

etc., etc.

PS to make this precise I guess you need a choice function to choose the bounded linear functionals $\beta_i$ too...

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought in the comment  section a while ago too… But what about having a point in the circle and creating a closed subspace far from $x_1$ in distance?

Comment: @Kadmos:  If $\|x\|$=1, Hahn-Banach gives a linear functional $\beta$ such that $\beta(x)=1$ and $|\beta(y)|\le\|y\|$ for all $y\in X$.  $\ker\beta$ has co-dimension one, and for all $y\in\ker\beta$, $1=|1-0|=|\beta(x)-\beta(y)|=|\beta(x-y)|\le\|x-y\|$.